# Cannot Parse String via JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm dynamically generate tables row (buttons) using JS- Ajax.when i parse a numeric value `removeProduct` function return the alert. but i cant get alert if i parse a String. can anyone help me to solve this problem

problem is in this line :
`onclick='removeProduct( " + prcode + " )'`

how to parse a String via function? (as a JavaScript String)

```
var single = alldata[i].split("##");
            var rows = "";

            var prcode = single[1];

            rows += "<td><a class='btn' onclick='removeProduct( " + prcode + " )' href='#'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a></td></tr>";
            $(rows).appendTo("#tblproductslist tbody");
```

Function :

```
    function removeProduct(str) {
    alert(str);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to pass a string literal, so try to enclose the value in `""`

```
onclick='removeProduct(\"" + prcode + "\")'
```

---

Since you are working with jquery, I would recommend you use event delegation to handle event and the data-api to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
rows += "<td><a class='btn' onclick='removeProduct( \"" + prcode + "\" )' href='#'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a></td></tr>";
```

If "prcode" is a string you must to quote it or it will be treated as (undefined) variable and will trigger an error.

Good luck!